# how to do controller initialization in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a `State` in my router which connects an outlet using my view class `UserApp.RegistrationView`.  Creation of the right controller class for that view, `RegistrationController`, seems to work magically based on convention:

```
registration: Em.State.extend({
    route: '/reg',
    registrationModel: null,
    connectOutlets: function (router) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet(UserApp.RegistrationView, UserApp.RegistrationModel.create());
    }
})
```

So I do not control creation of the controller, BUT I would like to run some initialization code when a controller is created.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of initialization ? The controller is looked up, and then injected by the framework.
Anyway, with the latest version of emberjs, you can pass an instance of a controller to connectOutlet.

@see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/be69395f5eec4187b1df052d7386bcda45f79475

Comment: I figured out the view is returned by connectOutlet, and from there I can "get" the controller (so then can call my own initialize() method).  But the update you linked to should make it a little cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd better go directly to the source code of built ember.js from master branch. The code annotations are more informative.